# AWS Billing(Usage + rateCard)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to get AWS usage report in .net using SDk or Rest API. Is there any service available for it?
To get rate card(pricing info) i have used
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonCloudWatch/current/index.json
this service from which i could get the json object.

Please advice if there is any such service avaialble to get the resources consumed in AWS. SO that i can calculate the billing.

Regards,
Aparna

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to cover several items:

1. Authentication - You'll need to set up your credentials to be able to connect to AWS. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)
2. Enable DBR or CUR reports in the billing console. This will export your monthly billing information to S3. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-gettingstarted-turnonreports.html)
3. Once ready use the SDK to download the reports and import them to DB, ES, whatever you're working with to process large excel files. Check the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html)

Good luck!